# Как использовать несколько возвращаемых значений функции в другой функции на Python

Tags: python, функции, return, аргументы

Хочу на Python использовать в другой функции возвращаемые значения этой функции как аргументы.
Как сделать так чтобы они сохранялись и мне не приходилось несколько раз вызывать функцию?

```
import random
def random_generator(duration):

    random_words = []
    random_nums = []

    while duration != 0:
        #Words
        words = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Pig', 'Parrot']
        num_of_word = int(random.randint(0, 3))
        word_random = words[num_of_word]
        random_words.append(word_random)
        #Nums
        num_random = int(random.randint(0, 7))
        random_nums.append(num_random)
        duration -= 1
    return random_words, random_nums
```

Comment: `a,b = random_generator(duration)`

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
...
def new_func(l=random_generator(12)):
    print(f'random_words = {l[0]}')
    print(f'random_nums  = {l[1]}')

new_func()
```

> random_words = ['Dog', 'Parrot', 'Pig', 'Pig', 'Parrot', 'Cat', 'Pig', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat']
>
> random_nums  = [2, 6, 5, 5, 0, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 1, 5]

Answer (score 0):

Я подозреваю вас, что вы вашей функцией `random_generator()` хотите придумать то, что уже давно придумано.

Это функция [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences).

Я использую ваши имена переменных и параметра, чтобы ясно было:

```
words = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Pig', 'Parrot']
nums = range(0, 8)

duration = 7         # например

random_words = random.choices(words, k=duration)
random_nums = random.choices(nums, k=duration)
```

---

Тест — пример использования:

```
print(random.choices(words, k=4), 
      random.choices(nums,  k=8))
```

> ```
> ['Cat', 'Parrot', 'Pig', 'Parrot'] [3, 0, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6]
> ```